# Out of Context and selecting filled in values in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am having 2 issues that I've been trying to solve all day. First off whenever I try to watch any variable no matter what it says  in the watches bar. I tried even just setting a variable to equal a number and watching it and it still gave me .

Second I am trying to put all of the values in column B that have a value into an array (TagName) and it is driving me up a wall. This is the point of the for loop. The out of context thing is not helping the case.

Just for reference "ist" was i as a string but then I added the B just to shorten the code.

Don't worry about the extra dims those are for code that is already working

Thank you for your help!

```
Sub GenTags()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
Dim TagName(100) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ist As String

Sheets("Parameters").Activate


For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("B").End(xlDown).Row
  ist = "B" & CStr(i)
  TagName(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range(ist)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the `ist` part - this would even be more clear: `TagName(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters").Range("B"&i).Value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want cells with values, you should probably have that as part of your loop. I think this should work. I also changed the array to be a variant in case you have a mix of string and numbers.

```
Sub GenTags()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim OutputFileNum As Integer
Dim TagName(100) As Variant
Dim i As Long, c As Long
Dim ist As String

Sheets("Parameters").Activate


For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Columns("B").End(xlDown).Row
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & i)) Then
        TagName(c) = Range("B" & i).Value
        c = c + 1
    End If


Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is a little more granular and takes care of empty cells in the column.

It's easy just yo customize the ">>>>" section

```
Sub GenTags()

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim OutputFileNum As Integer


Dim ist As String

' Define object variables
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim paramSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim cellEval As Range

' Define other variables
Dim sourceSheetName As String
Dim paramSheetName As String
Dim sourceColumn As String


Dim tagName() As Variant
Dim counter As Long ' before i
Dim nonBlankCounter As Long
Dim totalCells As Long


' >>> Customize to fit your needs
sourceSheetName = "Sheet1"
paramSheetName = "Parameters"
sourceColumn = "B"

' Initialize objects - Change sheets names
Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sourceSheetName)
Set paramSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(paramSheetName)
Set sourceRange = Application.Union(sourceSheet.Columns(sourceColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants), sourceSheet.Columns(sourceColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))

' Get how many items in column b are
totalCells = sourceRange.Cells.Count

' Redimension the array to include all the items
ReDim tagName(totalCells)

' Initilize the counter (for documentation sake)
counter = 0

For Each cellEval In sourceRange

    ' Add non empty values
    If Trim(cellEval.Value) <> vbNullString Then

        ' Store it in the array
        tagName(counter) = cellEval.Value

        counter = counter + 1

    End If

Next cellEval

' Redim to leave only used items
ReDim Preserve tagName(counter - 1)

End Sub
```

Let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses. Unfortunatley I had to put this project on the back burner until yesterday but I did try both answers and they didn't work. I decided to go a different direction with the entire code and got it working. Thank you for your help and sorry for the late response.